# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute and Excluding Certain Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I've created a custom AuthorizeAttribute to add a level of permission security to my application.

```
[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="Read")]
```

I can decorate certain actions in my controller or just implement it on the entire class. I have certain controllers with a large number of actions with only a few that don't need this extra check. It makes more sense for me to apply this to the entire class and exclude a few actions.

How can I exclude actions from my custom AuthorizeAttribute? It seems as though every time the action is run it default to the class attribute rather than any attribute I provide for that specific action.

Comment: Check out [ConditionalFilterProvider](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx)